# Flutter card top radius is covered by Image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**When I add a image to the card, the Radius  at the top of the card are covered. How can I solve it?**

When I add a image to the card, the Radius  at the top of the card are covered. How can I solve it?

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo'),),
          body: SizedBox(
              height: 310.0,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 3.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 0.0,),
                    Image.network('https://img.zcool.cn/community/012157578c405f0000012e7e69e7cd.jpg@1280w_1l_2o_100sh.jpg'),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(width: 16.0,),
                        Text('素雪', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,),
                        SizedBox(width: 16.0,),
                        Text('吉时已到', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                  ],
                ),
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the rendering

[image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can set `clipBehavior` for Card:

```
Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer, ...
```

Or you can wrap your image in `ClipRRect`

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(4.0)),
  child: Image.network(...),
)
```

Comment: adding clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer to card didn't work for me

Comment: Can't say anything - it worked in my code. You can try second solution

Comment: Somehow `clipBehavior ` didn't work for hot-reload but manual reload.

Comment: Combining both together works fine for webView Child in card

Comment: Better to use `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` for the small border-radius because it's **faster and performant than other clipping modes**.

Comment: yup, visal is right, clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer is very costly in performance. use Clip.hardEdge instead. you can see from the documentation in here https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/clip-behavior#migration-guide

Answer (score 9):

You need to put your image in a `Container` or a `DecoratedBox` and set the `BorderRadius` on the `BoxDecoration`.

```
     children: <Widget>[
        .....
        Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          height: 220.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(5.0)),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://img.zcool.cn/community/012157578c405f0000012e7e69e7cd.jpg@1280w_1l_2o_100sh.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ...
      ]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put the image in `Material` and set the `Border Radius` and `Clip Behaviour`.

```
    Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            elevation: 2.0,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: Image.asset(
              "images/user.png",
              height: 150,
              width: double.infinity,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
```

[image: Refer this Image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer` if you really care about the performance. Use a `Container` or a `DecoratedBox` with a `BorderRadius` as mentioned in chemamolins'answer.
Refer to [Performance best practices](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices#apply-effects-only-when-needed)

Comment: It would have been better if you provide information about the performance you are referring. Those who are interested will then decide to go to your provided link.