# Flutter How to create Card with background Image?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a Card with an Image as a background. The problem is, the Image overflows the Card, so the Corners of the don't show up.

I need to either set the Image as a background of the card or set the cards overflow behavior to no overflow. But I couldn't find any properties for that.

Here is my Card:

```
Widget _buildProgrammCard() {
  return Container(
    height: 250,
    child: Card(
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/push.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    ),
  );
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53275749/7130820 here is the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter card top radius is covered by Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267675/flutter-card-top-radius-is-covered-by-image)

Comment: Those are the largest images in the world!

Comment: @fantasitcalbeastly yeah thats just a regular screenshot. I got a hight resolution.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Other Way Without using - `ClipRRect` Widget - is To set `semanticContainer: true,` of `Card` Widget.

Example Code as Below:

```
Card(
          semanticContainer: true,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          child: Image.network(
            'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          elevation: 5,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        ),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work properly. I get white edges left and right of the Image

Comment: Now it still overflows the Card and hides the corners, just like the 1st picture.

Comment: Yeah I needed to restart. Now it works. I like this solution better then just giving the Image the same corners, so I will accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: What about if I need to add more widgets to the card?

Comment: `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,` is important, otherwise you won't have correct rounded borders on the card after adding the background image.

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap your image in `ClipRRect`

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10.0)),
  child: Image.network(...),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! so I just give the Image the same Radius? I guess that works but doesn't seem like the most elegant solution

Comment: I don't know another solutions. You can use `Material` instead of `Card`, but it has the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I also wanted to add a background image to my Card and I found a way. It's by wrapping a Card into Container and then using the BoxDecoration to add DecorationImage in the image property and then adding Image. A change is to be made in Card as well otherwise you will just see the inserted image behind the card, you have to make it transparent. There are different ways to achieve it.

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579202673506-ca3ce28943ef"),
                  fit:BoxFit.cover
                ),
              ),child: Card(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                  child: Text('Heyyyy')))
```

You can anytime wrap Card in Opacity widget and change its Transparency as per your need and also providing colors that way with a similar image might turn out to look aesthetic.
[Here is how it looks!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28u0D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to show the Card corner to draw above the image now use

```
borderOnForeground: true
```

Comment: That's the default value for the Card widget...

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Ejemplo"),
        ),
        body: Center(child: SwipeList()));
  }
}

class SwipeList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ListItemWidget();
  }
}

class ListItemWidget extends State<SwipeList> {
  List items = getDummyList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(items[index]),
              background: Container(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.delete,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                setState(() {
                  items.removeAt(index);
                });
              },
              direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
              child: Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 12),
                  elevation: 8,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                  semanticContainer: true,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 135,
                    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned(
                          top: 0,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Image.network(
                                    'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ))),
                      Positioned(
                          top: 20,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(items[index],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ]),
                  )),
            );
          },
        ));
  }

  static List getDummyList() {
    List list = List.generate(5, (i) {
      return "Item ${i + 1}";
    });
    print(list);
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code  may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
class CardView extends StatelessWidget {

  const CardView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 250,
      width: double.maxFinite,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        image: const DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage(
              "https://images.pexels.com/photos/20522325/pexels-photo-20522325/free-photo-of-pier-at-the-beach.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        child: const Center(
            child: Text("Pier at the beach"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```