# Network image fit to card without loosing card shape with grid view in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, material-design

In the wanted view, there is a grid list with two columns and its items design needs to set an image in the card's background and cards have some radius, Image is network image but card size is fluctuating according to the network image. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866481/flutter-how-to-create-card-with-background-image) too but not working.

Here is the code

```
Container(
  child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(
                    child: Card(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          child: Image.network(
                            event_response.imageLogoUrl +
                                event_response.eventList[position].event_logo,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                          Container(
                           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                           child  :Text('${event_response.eventList[position].eventName}'),
                        )
                      ],

                );},),),],),);
```

Here I want but in 2 columns.

[image]

here I'm getting

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to round the corners of the images, you have to wrap it in ClipRRect widget and give it border radius same as your card.

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
  Expanded(
    child: Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      child: Image.network(
            event_response.imageLogoUrl +
                event_response.eventList[position].event_logo,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        )),
  ),
  Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: Text('${event_response.eventList[position].eventName}'),
  )
]);
```

Comment: your code is working but somewhere cards size is small, perhaps you have seen in the image that last two cards is wrapped according to image size but card showing radius too.

Comment: @farhana Sorry, can you explain again in what way my code is not working?

Comment: i need to set set image width to `matchparent`.

Comment: ` ClipRRect` is working but width of the grid cell is wrapped according to image size.

Comment: @farhana I added crossAxisAlignment to column. I think this will do what you want to do.

Comment: now i applied ` crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` it is working

Comment: @farhana I'm glad I was able to help. If you don't mind, checkout my other answers in flutter tag.

Comment: would you like see my another question on StackOverflow flow

Comment: @farhana sure, let me take a look

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `Card` into `Expanded` and use `BoxFit.cover` for your `Image`.

```
                Column(children: <Widget>[
                     Expanded(
                        child: Card(
                             clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
                             child: Image.network(event_response.imageLogoUrl+event_response.eventList[position].event_logo, fit: BoxFit.cover,
                             )
                             ),
                         ),
                      Container(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                       child  :Text('${event_response.eventList[position].eventName}'),
                    )
```

Comment: the code is fitting the image but the card losing its radius and its view.

Comment: sorry I forgot the clipBehavior inside the Card, answer updated!

Comment: that's weird, try using antiAliasWithSaveLayer , and hot restart .